# Testing connection on .Net via ODP without user name and password

Tags: c#, odp.net

I'm working on a desktop application on `C#` and `Oracle DB`. I connect to `DB` via a `connection string` consisting of `UserName`, `Password` and `DataSet` using `ODP`.

On the application before the `Login Screen` appears i want to check if the `client` can reach the `DB Machine` and if there is no connection the application will give an error(there is no DB connection) and close.
Is there a way to test the connection.
The best way i thought is to get the `ip` and `port from` `tnsnames.ora` and `ping` that `ip`. If this is suitable how can i get `ip` and `port` from `tnsnames.ora` on `C#`?

Comment: If you're testing a connection to see if the database is online, pinging the machine won't do. The network interface (i.e.: the LAN or Wifi chipset) might respond even though the database process is not running in the machine.

Comment: Yes that's true. May be i can send a request to the port number of oracle db.

Comment: Or may be i can send a connection.Open() request with an empty username and password and check the exception if timeout or wrong passsword. Should i parse the exception string for detecting this?

Comment: You had a good idea there. Usually these exceptions are typed, and they come with some sort of error code, so you could go that way.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a command line utility `tnsping`
You can create a process, run this command and parse the output to get the data.

tnsping TNSname

It should return "OK (n msec)" or "Failed to resolve name" at the end of return data buffer